# Docker Rails App migration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having an issue migrating my rails app data. I can get the app running fine using eb local run, then migrating the data using docker exec  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production and it runs the migrations. However when I ssh into my EB instance and run the same command, the console hangs and the health shifts to warning, saying 100% cpu in use and 97% in i/o wait.

**edit: in the logs I see PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known... again it runs fine locally so not sure what the issue is.

**edit2 (additional details:)

Steps taken on local machine:

1) eb local run

2) open new terminal, obtain running docker id using docker ps (output below)

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES`

`<docker id>        <imagename>   "rake run"               13 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                 elasticbeanstalk_web_1`

`<docker_id>        postgres:latest         "/docker-entrypoint.s"   14 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5433->5431/tcp   elasticbeanstalk_db_1`

3) docker exec  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
4) app migrates successfully

When I ssh into the aws container
1) docker ps

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES`

`<container id>        <image name>            "rake run"               2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                 ecs-awseb-app-env-apwxtv5mzf-8-web-aa9ca28485ed8ee69c01`

`<container id>        postgres                         "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5433->5431/tcp   ecs-awseb-app-env-apwxtv5mzf-8-db-8cb4a4b9daa3d8a50100`

`81ef33210e3a        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest   "/agent"                 19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         127.0.0.1:51678->51678/tcp         ecs-agent`

2) docker exec  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
3) receive error: PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known rake aborted!

**dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
RUN gem update --system 2.6.1
RUN gem install bundler --version $BUNDLER_VERSION

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /box
RUN bundle install

ADD . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["rake"]
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
        "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
        "containerDefinitions": [{
            "name": "db",
            "image": "postgres",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 128,
            "portMappings": [{
                "hostPort": 5433,
                "containerPort": 5431
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "box",
            "image": "busybox",
            "essential": false,
            "memory": 128,
            "volumes": [{
                "host": {
                    "sourcePath": "/box"
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "web",
            "image": "hughkolias/yuhu:test4",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 128,
            "command": [
                "run"
            ],
            "volumes": [{
                "host": {
                    "sourcePath": ".:/yuhu"
                }
            }],
            "portMappings": [{
                "hostPort": 80,
                "containerPort": 80
            }],
            "links": [
                "db"
            ]
        }]
    }
```

Any help on migrating would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? How are you setting up the environment in each place? Are you using simple `docker run` commands or something like docker-compose? It sounds like you are running a postgres container when you run it locally but not when running on the remote.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Hope the new edit provides better insight!